# diff won't work recursively

Tags: command-line, diff, osx-el-capitan, recursive

I'm trying to recursively diff two directories using the command line `diff` util. I have two folders, `diff1` and `diff2`, with contents like this:

[image]

`diff2` is empty. But when I do `diff -r diff1 diff2` I only get

```
$ diff -r diff1 diff2
Only in diff1: folder
Only in diff1: test.html
```

This is vexing. What do I need to do to get `diff` working recursively? I've tried `--recursive`, but that doesn't help. I'm on El Capitan, and a `diff -v` gets me `diff (GNU diffutils) 2.8.1`.

Comment: what would you expect output to be when one folder is empty?  Nothing to diff really. It tells you whats in diff1. That is the difference.  Have you tried putting a file in diff2? Or the file test.html with edited differences.

Comment: Looks like it is working...

Comment: @john, I'd expect the diff to recurse into the directory called folder - I mean what about another-folder, hello-txt and test2.html? When I read "recursively" I assume that the process won't stop at the first level.

Comment: oh sorry, i missed that.  Have you tried a capital R?  as in -R

Comment: no that won't work as there is no -R option. Sorry again. -r should work, I'm as baffled as you are... Unless the empty directory is confusing it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you experienced is by design. I don't think you can get what you want, unless you allow tools other than `diff`. From your comment:

> When I read "recursively" I assume that the process won't stop at the first level.

It doesn't stop because of the first level. Mind what recursion means:

> using functions that **call themselves from within their own code**

<sup>(source: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)); emphasis mine)</sup>

Imagine you have a common subdirectory `foo` in both `diff1` and `diff2`. Recursion means that your original command `diff -r diff1 diff2` at some point calls

```
diff -r diff1/foo diff2/foo
```

OK, in practice this is most likely done by a subroutine calling itself within a single process (but I guess an implementation that actually calls `diff` executable is possible). Still logically it's like this.

You have `diff1/folder` but there's no `diff2/folder`. How can you call `diff` to compare these? In other words, what should `<unknown_name>` be, so you get your desired output from the below form?

```
diff -r diff1/folder diff2/<unknown_name>
```

There is no `<unknown_name>` that fits. Recursive `diff` cannot descend to `folder` without turning into something like recursive `ls` or `find`. Being recursive `ls` or `find` is not its job.

Still you can query `diff1/folder` with `ls -R` or `find` (recursive by default), after you learn from `diff` that `Only in diff1: folder`.